Does a No Indexed Page Show Ads
I am Working on APK and MOD apps/games and create noindex page for every mod/apk. Should I enable manual ads on that particular page or It will be against google adsense community guidlines.
Please share your valuable thoughts.

A "noindex" page directive prevents search engines from indexing the page, but it doesn't affect the display of ads. Ads can still appear on a noindexed page if the ad-serving system or code is present and active.

noindex does not affect ad display; it simply prevents indexing by search engine bots.
Please note that content associated with illegal or unauthorised material: modified apps, pirated software and hacked APK files violates Google AdSense policy.
Displaying ads on such pages can result in penalties, including the blocking  of your AS account.
So I wouldn't recommend you to do that, it's better to find other monetisation formats.
